# How to set base image for DockerPlugin of sbt native packager?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to dockerify a scala application.

I use the `sbt-native-packager`, and when building the image locally via

```
sbt docker:publishLocal
```

I was surprised to realize that it would use:

```
openjdk:latest
```

as its base image.

I like to point my docker image against certain version, and I know that my application currently require Java 8 and will crash on Java 9; and the `latest` tag might point to a new major version in the future.

I am a bit confused on how the Docker plugin works through sbt-native-packager. Why is it using `openjdk:latest` as its base? How can I set it to something different, e.g.: `openjdk/8-jdk`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the baseImage and its tag in your build.sbt through:

```
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8-jdk"
```

You can read about this in the [docker documentation of the sbt native packager](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/docker.html?highlight=Base%20Image).